# DNS: What exactly is the SOA hostmaster?

Tags: domain-name-system, soa-record

I know that by default the value for a SOA record's RP is "hostmaster". I presume this is an alias, but what for? And would it make any difference if I put Administrator@domain.com instead of *hostmaster*?

Answer (score 7):

[RFC 1035 3.3.13.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.13) on *SOA RDATA format* specifies `RNAME` as

> A `<domain-name>` which specifies the mailbox of the person responsible for this zone.

RIPE [Recommendations for DNS SOA Values](https://www.ripe.net/publications/docs/ripe-203) clarifies this a lot:

> The RNAME is to publish a mail address of a person or role account
> dealing with this zone with the `@` converted to a `.`. The best
> practice is to define (and maintain) a dedicated mail alias
> `hostmaster` ([RFC 2142, 7.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142#section-7)) for DNS operations.

So you can use `administrator@example.com` (converted to `administrator.example.com`), but it's recommended and conventional, for *simplicity and regularity*, to use the `hostmaster` alias. Of course, if you haven't set up the alias on your mail server, it would be more wrong to publish a non-existent address instead of an unconventional address.